# Using reflection to get child class from base class

Tags: .net, inheritance, reflection

Say I have the following class model:

```
Class1 -> BaseClass
```

or

```
Class2 -> BaseClass
```

Class1 has properties of

```
public string Property1 { get; set; }
public int Property2 { get; set; }
```

Class2 has properties of

```
public double Property1 { get; set; }
public string Property2 { get; set; }
public int Property3 { get; set; }
```

I would like to create a method in BaseClass that will create a hash for all the properties in whichever child class has been instantiated.  How can I, using reflection, get the properties of the child class?

Since .Net doesn't allow multiple inheritance, I assume I'd be safe assuming there is only 1 child class (or a single line of child classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're just looking for using `GetType()`, which will give the execution-time type of the current object:

```
foreach (var property in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var value = property.GetValue(this, null);
    // Whatever
}
```

When called on an instance of `Class1`, that should show `Property1` and `Property2` even though the code is in `BaseClass`.